# ASP.NET ressource file in iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, localization

I have a c# asp.net application with the framework v4.0 . In my application, I am using some resx file. When I locally run my application, all is normal (the localization work pretty well). Now I am trying to setup my application on iis 8 (The server with iis is a 2012 r2). The problem is all the control that are using the resx file to get the text property are empty.

So, given that all is working good locally and not on iis, is that iis need some special configuration to use the resx file properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you run it locally, are you running it through visual studio or are you running it off a local version of IIS? There are differences between configuration of IIS in visual studio and the "real" IIS, so you might want to start there. Also, are there any errors or warning being generated in the event viewer?

Comment: I am running it on a 2012 r2 server (not local)